# How to add a string to a list if its not none into a list?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Below code used for web scraping data from a website. And this code will write relevant information to an excel file. But if there is no element in the data[x][y] it's throwing an error. Sometimes values may not be present in the data[x][y] is throwing index out of range exception. Added full code to get more information.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from xlwt import Workbook
import openpyxl
from openpyxl.styles.borders import Border, Side
from openpyxl.utils import get_column_letter
from openpyxl.styles import Alignment

website_url = "https://www.example.com/"
res = requests.get(website_url, verify=False)
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text, 'lxml')
Links = soup.find_all("a", {"class": "jobTitleLink"},)
url = [tag.get('href') for tag in Links]
wb = openpyxl.Workbook()

# Write a header row
columns = [
    ("SL No", 10),
    ("Job Title", 25),
    ("Company Name", 20),
    ("Posted on", 13),
    ("Closing on", 13),
    ("Location", 20),
    ("Description", 40),
    ("Skills", 70),
    ("Link Email", 30),
]

thin_border = Border(left=Side(style='thin'), right=Side(
    style='thin'), top=Side(style='thin'), bottom=Side(style='thin'))
ws = wb.active

for col_number, (value, width), in enumerate(columns, start=1):
    ws.cell(column=col_number, row=1, value=value).border = thin_border
    ws.column_dimensions[get_column_letter(col_number)].width = width

row_number = 2



for x in url[1:5]:
    res = requests.get(f'https://www.example/com/{x}', verify=False)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text, 'lxml')
    data = []

    for div_block in soup.find_all('div', class_='block', style=None):
        data.append([line.strip() for line in div_block.stripped_strings])

    li_fr = soup.find('li', class_="fr")
    company_name = li_fr.a.text
    location = list(li_fr.find_next_sibling('li').stripped_strings)[1]

    # Write a data row
    row = [
        '',  # SL No
        data[0][0],  # **Need check these values exists before saving** 
        company_name,  # Company name
        data[1][1],
        data[2][1],
        location,
        data[4][1],
        '\n'.join(data[5][1:]),
        data[3][1],
    ]

    for col_number, value in enumerate(row, start=1):
        cell = ws.cell(column=col_number, row=row_number, value=value)
        cell.border = thin_border
        cell.alignment = Alignment(wrapText=True)

    row_number += 1

wb.save('output.xlsx')
print('Saved all the data')
```

Comment: Is `data[8][0]` the only item which could possibly be `None`?

Comment: Nope. All strings have chances to be none

Comment: `row = list(filter(None, [... what you have above]))` might be a workaround to help you omit too many if clauses to skip adding None's. However, I'm really not sure what is inside your `data`, so it's really hard for me to tell you a possibly better approach.

Comment: It didn't work. Am getting list index out of range error

Comment: Please update your question with the full error traceback

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is to define a sentinal value, one which none of the items can possibly be it you want to keep them, but you can selectively substitute for `data[8][0]`.

```
def item_or_sentinal(item, sentinal=tuple()):
    return sentinal if item is None else item

row = [
        row_number-1, 
        item_or_sentinal(data[8][0]), 
        data[7][1],  
        data[1][1], 
        data[2][1], 
        '\n'.join(data[4][1:]),  
        '\n'.join(data[5][1:]), 
        data[3][1],  # Email
    ]

sentinal = item_or_sentinal(None)
row = [item for item in row if item is not sentinal]
```

Comment: It's not working. Throwing list index out of range exception

Comment: What do you want to happen when the indexes are out of range?